# JobScheduler getting change Contacts Id

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-jobscheduler

I have a question about JobScheduler and would be very happy if someone could solve my problem. I have a Trigger-based Job watching for changes in the Contact photo on an android phone:

```
static {
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JobIds.PHOTOS_CONTENT_JOB,
        new ComponentName("com.android.agent", AgentService.class.getName()));
builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(
        ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_URI,
        JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS));
builder.setTriggerContentMaxDelay(1000);
JOB_INFO = builder.build();
}
```

I get a reaction from the phone and a URI, the problem I have is the only URI information I get is: ***content://com.android.contacts***
What I need is some kind of information on what Contact just changed or what Id the photo just added have.

If someone could help, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Not the same question as [Android - Get only newest contacts that were added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658649/android-get-only-newest-contacts-that-were-added/45660154#45660154) but the same answer)

Starting with API level 18, you can use `Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`, so it's possible to query for all contacts that had been modified (or created) recently, and compare only those to your last cache of contact ids, and the delta would be the contacts created/modified since the last time your code ran.

Comment: Well, I still have a problem getting any information out from this.